# Three tiered security check; session still vulnerable?

Tags: php, security, session

I have a basic site I'm using to test my programming method and I want to get a semi-decent secure way of keeping people logged in. Here is the code for `register.php`.

```
$username = $_POST["username"]; //username stored plaintext
$passhashed = crypt($_POST["password"], $username); //hashed password salted with username
$rnum = rand(1000,9999); //assign random 4-digit number
$authkey = crypt($rnum, $passhashed); //unique authentication key per user, hashed and salted with hashed password
//insert into SQL
```

When they log-in, `$username`, `$passhashed`, and `$authkey` is stored in `$_SESSION` data.

At the top of every single page I have the following snippet of code:

```
if(isset($_SESSION["username"])
&& isset($_SESSION["password"])
&& isset($_SESSION["authkey"])) {
    $verifyuser = $db->prepare("
        SELECT *
            FROM users
            WHERE username = :user
            AND password = :password
            AND authkey = :authkey
    ");
    $verifyuser->execute(array(
        ':user' => $_SESSION["username"],
        ':password' => $_SESSION["password"],
        ':authkey' => $_SESSION["authkey"]));
    if($verifyuser->rowCount() != 1) {
        unset($_SESSION["username"]);
        unset($_SESSION["password"]);
        unset($_SESSION["authkey"]);
    }
}
```

Basically on any given page, it performs a check that each piece store in `$_SESSION` clears with SQL, and if not (if any of the checks fail, will give a `rowCount` of not 1), it drops the session.

I'll be the first to admit I'm not too familiar with contemporary security measures to evade session hijacking (in fact, I only have a loose command of how it is even done). That being said, how is this for a beginner programmer? What can I do different to make it more secure? Assign a second authentication key at login, temporarily store it in SQL and make the same checks (new key per login)?

Comment: unless your running a bank, its probably good enough

Comment: I figured it wasn't important to mention, but `$_SESSION` data is kept alive for days with `ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', 60*60*24*3);` and `ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 60*60*24*3);`.

Comment: So I was right, that normally the SESSION would not exist. But that does not work anyway. Users will get a new session id when they come back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The `crypt` function](http://www.php.net/crypt) is somewhat out-of-date. You'd be better off using bcrypt, which is provided in PHP using [`password_hash`](http://www.php.net/password_hash) and [`password_verify`](http://www.php.net/password_verify). Additionally, using those functions, the salt (what you call `$authkey`) is integrated into the string, so you don't need to store it separately.

I notice you're storing the username and password in `$_SESSION`. `$_SESSION` cannot be directly modified by the client, so you might be better off just storing the user's ID there.

Comment: Cheers. I'm always looking for more relevant and secure methods of hashing. In fact, up until a few days ago I was only using `md5()` thinking it had even a modicum of security. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

As you mentioned, I too have a basic understanding of session hijacking.

However I think if these 3 were hijacked, this still may not prevent account hijacking, although does make it harder.

When reading preventing session hijacking, I saw an example as simple as - If the current IP doesn't match the session, log the user out.

```
<?php
if($_SESSION['ip'] != $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])
{
session_destroy();
}
?>
```

Typical: I can no longer find said website...

Some links that may help you:

[Preventing session hijacking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12233406/preventing-session-hijacking)

[Proper session hijacking prevention in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8419332/proper-session-hijacking-prevention-in-php)

Comment: That's actually a pretty simple yet great way to do things. I've appended that to my code, thanks!

Comment: No problem - But please take into account what has been said on the links I included - If you haven't already looked, as there may be a genuine reason behind IP changes.

Comment: bad idea, ip!=person, can easily change legitimately between requests.

Comment: @Dagon, I think the point is that `$_SESSION['ip']` is assigned at every login; it just ensures that session is kept alive while that person--and solely that person--is logged into their account. If the session is hijacked, it drops the moment it detects a mismatch between IP in session and IP of visitor.

Comment: ip can change with out it being a hijack

Comment: @Dagon As I mentioned to riista - It doesn't necessarily mean a hijack, but it's an extra measure you _can_ introduce.