# PHP $_SESSION is not cleared, nor is it set. Always returns NULL

Tags: php, session

I am relatively new to PHP, so I realize this is very likely a beginners mistake; but I have done my due diligence and I have attempted to trouble-shoot the issue on my own, but with no luck.

First, I pass the values myusername and mypassword from the form to checklogin.php.  From there it queries the database, and if a single row is returned where the username and password match,  this code is run:

```
$_SESSION['myusername']=$myusername;
$_SESSION['mypassword']=$mypassword;
header("location:login_success.php");
}
else {
echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}
?>
```

Now, I understand writing your own login mechanism is frowned upon --especially since mine doesn't even work.  I understand this; but at this point, getting it to work is more of a learning experience for myself than a practical application.

From here I am directed to this page (‍login_success.php‍), which should only load if ‍$_SESSION['myusername']‍ is set or rather, I am "logged in".

```
<?php
session_start();
var_dump($_SESSION);
if(!isset($_SESSION['myusername'])){
header("location:login.php");
}

var_dump($_SESSION['myusername']);
var_dump($_SESSION['mypassword']);

?>

<html>
<body>
Login Successful
</body>
</html>
```

Now, immediately after logging in, both `var_dumps` output `NULL`.  If I pull the whole ‍`$_SESSION‍` array I get ‍‍‍`arra‍y(0) { }`.

Now, I also have a logout.php function:

```
<?php
session_start();
unset($_SESSION['myusername']);
$_SESSION = array();
session_destroy();
header("location:dashboard.php");
?>
```

a `var_dump` of `$_SESSION['myusername']` still shows `NULL`, and a `var_dump` of `$_SESSION` is `array(0) { }.  Which is expected; HOWEVER when I got to`login_success.php`, which should only load if`$_SESSION['myusername']`is set, it will still load; but the`var_dumps`of the`$_SESSION`array still show`NULL`.

So, two issues.  After setting my session tokens they are always null; and after `unsetting`/`session_destory()`ing my $_SESSION, I can still access a page that checks to see if `$_SESSION['myusername']` is set.

Does anyone know what could cause this behavior?

Comment: so did you start the session in all files using it? doesn't look like it in your first body of code. check for errors http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: And *if* you've got session_start() at the top of all relevant scripts, you should then investigate the values in phpinfo() that are session-relevant, especially session.cookie_domain, session.cookie_httponly, session.cookie_lifetime, session.cookie_secure, session.use_cookies, session.use_trans_sid, session.use_only_cookies, session.name, etc.

Inspection of cookies in your browser should yield a cookie with a name equal to session.name if your installation is working properly.

Comment: Read up on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8419332/proper-session-hijacking-prevention-in-php as well

Comment: Thanks, it turns out I was only invoking session_start() on login.php and logout.php, not the other pages.  I will read up on the other material provided, since this is more of a learning experience than a project. Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to have `session_start();` in every PHP file where you are working with `$_SESSION` variables. Make sure to include it on the top of the PHP file.

Also, are you submitting the form with method POST?  The variables you are posting are stored in a $_POST array, so:

```
$_SESSION['myusername']=$myusername;
$_SESSION['mypassword']=$mypassword;
```

should be:

```
$_SESSION['myusername']=$_POST['myusername'];
$_SESSION['mypassword']=$_POST['mypassword'];
```

Whenever submitting a password through a form, make sure to set the form attribute method to post, like so: `<form method="post">`

Comment: Perfect, that's what it was.  I was not calling session_start in all files; only login.php and logout.php.  However; I am still able to access login_success.php (which should only load if $_SESSION['myusername'] is set) after clearing them and setting $_SESSION = array();

Comment: Also, I have changed my `IF` statement in logout.php to `if(!isset($_SESSION['myusername']) or empty($_SESSION['myusername'])) {`.  I expected this to work; but I can still reach the page with my sessions unset and empty (null).