# PHP redirect on login failure

Tags: php, security

**SITUATION**

I have made the following login form:

```
<?php

 session_start();
 session_regenerate_id(TRUE);

 $username = $_POST['username'];
 $password  = $_POST['password'];
 $url_to_open_after_success_login = $_POST['sezione'];

 //Connect to my database
 try {

   $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=0.0.0.0;dbname=name', 'user', 'passw');
   $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

  } catch (PDOException $e) {

   echo "non riesco a connettere. perchè -> " . $e->getMessage();
   exit();

  }

  //The table "accessi" has 2 fields that are "username" and "password"
  //From this table I grab the data
  try {

   $query_mag = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM accessi WHERE username = ?");
   $query_mag->bindParam(1 , $username, PDO::PARAM_INT);
   $query_mag->execute();

  } catch (PDOException $e) {

   echo "Unable to execute the query. ". $e->getMessage();
   exit();

  }

  $dati_utente = $query_mag->fetch();

  //CHECK IF THE PASSWORD IS CORRECT OR NOT 
  if ( password_verify($password, $dati_utente[1]) ) {

   //login executed
   $_SESSION["login"] = 1;

   if ($url_to_open_after_success_login == 'something') {
    header('location: /blabla/aaa.php');
   } else {
    header('location: /blabla2/bbb.php');
   }

  } else {

   //WRONG PASSWORD! You are not allowed to access so go back to the home
   header('location: /');

  }

?>
```

The code above is pretty easy. I connect to the database, then I make a query to get the password (hashed of course) of a particular user. Then if the password is correct I am redirected to a page.

**Only** if the login successfully happened, I am using `$_SESSION["login"] = 1;`.

---

**PROBLEM**

On the top of each page I have the following code:

```
<?php

 session_start();
 if (!isset($_SESSION["login"])) { header('location: /error_page.php'); }

?>

<html> 
 <head>
  //html/css/js code here...
```

If you look at the PHP code, you can understand that (if the user did not log in successfully) the page immediatly redirects to the error page. My question is the following.

**Q:** is this a safe way to check if the user logged in? should I avoid this redirect-way and try something else?

---

When a logged member wants to log out, I have made a `logout.php` file that looks like this:

```
<?php

 session_start();
 session_regenerate_id(TRUE);
 $_SESSION = array();

 //delete the session cookie
 if (ini_get("session.use_cookies")) {
    $params = session_get_cookie_params();
    setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000,
        $params["path"], $params["domain"],
        $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]
    );
 }

 session_destroy();  
 header('location: /');

?>
```

Comment: Seems fine to me. EDIT- 1 Wrong password attempt and a redirection? Hm.. The user now has to click "Back" and attempt again and can possibly do this forever. Meaning he could make infinite amounts of database calls.

Comment: It has rhythm and I can dance to it.

Comment: @JayBlanchard You can dance on a safe PDO music

Comment: You SHOULD definitely use die() after any header command, as some browsers ignore it and it would continue executing the script, it's a Huge security flaw.

Comment: You mean the die(); in the logout.php or in the header?

Comment: @DK64 After the `header()`, you can call `exit()` as well.

Comment: ok I am calling header('/page.php'); and then exit();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of points for you

1. After you issue a `header` for redirection, I would issue an `exit;` next, to stop execution of the script. Redirection should be the last thing you do anyways, so this ensures nothing else in your script runs accidentally.
2. `$_SESSION` is safe enough, provided your end users don't have a direct way to set or unset the data there. There's always the risk of a session hijack, but that's a different problem.

Comment: Thank you, that is the answer that I wanted! I have included the exit() and I am redirecting to an error page. I have read the doc on php.net and in this way (with the exit();) I can't go back with the browser. Great! :)

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is not really safe because it missed some checks against session highjacking.

Additional you should store during the login the remote ip, remote agent and similar data on server side and compare it on every request to make (mostly) sure that the request comes from the right user.

See [Proper session hijacking prevention in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8419332/proper-session-hijacking-prevention-in-php) and [Preventing session hijacking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12233406/preventing-session-hijacking)

Comment: "checks against session hijacking" is really a thing?