# Alternative to using global variable strings and any security issues related around using them?

Tags: php, string, security, global-variables, global

I've tried to look for an answer to this, but none of the other articles seem to answer it as clearly for me.

I have made a lot of code where there are string variables that are being used when users jump from page to page and they are being used after setting a global $string; type deal

What are some of the better solutions to pass a variable to be used on another page in terms of being most secure?

Is using global $strings a bad thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Globals themselves won't allow you to keep variable values from page to page.

For that, you have to use as session mechanism (e.g. [with `$_SESSION` PHP magic array](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php)).

For security & sessions, see:

- http://php.net/manual/en/session.security.php
- [How safe are PHP session variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181105/how-safe-are-php-session-variables)

Comment: What if for example though on one page I have $string = "a"; and then later on the same page I go include("anotherpage.php"); and on anotherpage.php I go global $string; ..... is there any risk there? is there a better way to pass the value through? my only concern is I have about 4 or 5 variables I pass on from page to page, is session ideal for that if there are multiple values?

Comment: It's difficult to understand your concern: do you want to keep data across page loadings (several HTTP requests) or simply have access to a variable from your main PHP script in an 'included' script?

Comment: Recently I have been going through what I have already coded and I am looking for any holes in security, that is to say, any way a hacker could compromise any data. Seems to be the consensus not to trust anything from a user, validate it, scrub the data, filter it etc. My concern is if I have a string I am calling globally such as global $string; from a new page is there anyway a hacker could compromise and exploit this in some way, change the string to something else in mid swing when a user jumps to a new page that refers to a global $string

Comment: Thanks for your clarification. My answer: it depends on many things, but basically you are on the right way (never trust user input). Think about everything that could allow unwanted user output introduction, particularly the `register_globals` PHP setting (see http://www.php.net/manual/fr/ini.core.php#ini.register-globals) ; so dangerous that it has been purely *removed* from PHP 5.4.