# Is this scenario unsafe? (Updating MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql

I have a member only part of my site and I'm using a form for **me as the only user** to update a database.

The first thing that happens on the PHP-based form processing page is something along these lines...

```
if($_SESSION['member_id'] != 1){
   exit;
} else {
   //post stuff to db.
}
```

So, basically if your member_id isn't 1, then the script stops.

One piece of data I'll be posting is a string that may contain quotes.

Question: In this environment, can I simply use `addslashes()` for the string that may contain quotes and feel reasonably safe that I won't do something unintentionally bad to my database?

Thanks.

Comment: when querying a database, it's best to use prepared statements and guard again session hijacking and XSS exploits.

Comment: Check out [examples of sql injections through addslashes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/860954/examples-of-sql-injections-through-addslashes); as you [can steal someone's SESSION](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181105/how-safe-are-php-session-variables)

Comment: @Fred-ii-: Are "prepared statements" the same as "PDO"?  Any other security concerns with what I've laid out?

Comment: It comes in 2 flavours; for mysqli http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php and for PDO http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements that's assuming using MySQL.