# PHP: Is it a security problem, if I take the $_SESSION['userid'] as an identifier?

Tags: php, security, session

I have a login-system. When a user logs in the user data get stored in $_SESSION variables (id, username,...) like this (login.php):

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username';
$statement = $con->prepare($sql);
$result = $statement->execute(array('username' => $username));
$userdata = $statement->fetch();
$hashedPassword = json_encode($userdata['password']);

//check password
if ($result && password_verify($password, $userdata['password'])) {
session_regenerate_id();
$_SESSION['loggedIn'] = true;
$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
$_SESSION['id'] = $userdata['id'];
echo $_SESSION['id'];
echo 'true';
} else {
exit('false');
}
}else{
    exit('false');
}
```

Now my question: Is it a security problem, when I use this data as trustworthy data, maybe like:

```
INSERT INTO userRelatedTable (userId,data1,data2) VALUES ($_SESSION['userid'] (<= !!!) ,'data1','data2')
```

In other words: Does php handle the security part when i say session_start(); with a sessionkey, or do i have to generate a key, store it and use it as an identifier by myself?

Greetings

Comment: Can I assume your question is: "Is session data secure?"? There is lots of information on that, even here, for instance: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181105/how-safe-are-php-session-variables but also in the manual: https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.session.security.management.php

Answer (score 0):

Client-side cannot directly alter `$_SESSION` as it is stored server-side. However, implementation may make it possible:

```
$_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username']; // Now $_SESSION['username'] can be anything
```

`$_SESSION['id']` cannot SQL-inject if `id` is an integer field in your database. But for consistency and to be on the safe side of things you may want to use prepared statements here as well.